# How do I solve this system of linear equations using modular arithmetics

Tags: linear-algebra, modular-arithmetic, systems-of-equations

How do I solve this system of linear equations using augmented matrices $\mod 7$:

$3x + 6y + 2z = 1 \\
2x + 4y + z = 6 \\
4x + y + 2z = 5 ?$

A hint is given that the first calculation for Row 1 is:  $R1 = \alpha  R1$, where $3 \alpha = 1 \pmod 7$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

It is done by row reduction as usual, but you have to compute first the inverses modulo $7$. This is given by the following relations:
$$ 2\cdot 4=1,\quad 3\cdot5=1,\quad 6^2=1.$$

Then one should make each successive pivot equal to $1$,  multiplying each row with the inverse of the element in the same column as the pivot. This is how it goes:
$$\color{red}{\begin{matrix}{}\times 5\\{}\times4 \\{}\times2 \end{matrix}}\begin{bmatrix}
1&2&4&5\\1&2&4&3\\
1&2&4&4\end{bmatrix}$$
Thus, the system has no solution.

Comment: Thank you, I think I understand that. What row operations should I use to get to the solution?

Comment: You should make each successive pivot equal to $1$,  multiplying its row its inverse. Please see my completed answer.